# Accept a list of table names and col name in scala and return appended prefix on column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to take input from the user in the below form. There can be `n` number of `table_name` and `column_name` in this string.

Input structure:

```
input="tablename_1:column_name|tablename_2:column_name,tablename_1:column_name|tablename_2:column_name,tablename_1:column_name|tablename_3:column_name"
```

Real example:

```
input="customer:name|customer_tmp:name,customer:period|account:period,customer:id|balance:balance_id"
```

Logic that I want to implement:

- For table_name `customer_tmp` add suffix `pm_` in front of column (name in example).
- For table_name `account` add suffix `acct_` in front of column (period in example).
- For table_name `balance` add suffix `bal_` in front of column (balance_id in example).

Wanted output for the input example:

```
return_value="name|pm_name,period|acct_period,id|bal_balance_id"
```

How can this code be made as generic as possible?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to first split the input string into a list of tuples:

```
val split_input = input.split(",")
  .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.split(":")))
  .map(v => (v(1)(0), v(0)(1), v(1)(1)))
```

Printing with `foreach(println)` gives:

```
(customer_tmp,name,name)
(account,period,period)
(balance,id,balance_id)
```

Next we keep the wanted logic in a `Map` to allow for easy modification:

```
val prefix_logic = Map("customer_tmp" -> "pm_", "account" -> "acct_", "balance" -> "bal_")
```

Now, we can apply the logic and create the final string:

```
val split_output = split_input.map(v => (v._2, prefix_logic.get(v._1).get + v._3))

val return_value = split_output.map(v => v._1 + "|" + v._2).mkString(",")
```

Result:

```
name|pm_name,period|acct_period,id|bal_balance_id
```

Comment: Could you please provide solution to this question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784889/generate-id-in-spark-as-per-the-below-logic-in-spark-scala

Comment: Could you please provide the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366476/load-open-library-json-dump-to-a-hive-table-using-spark-scala